# Unable to identify the RadTreeView object using UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I have to expand the Radtreeview. But while recording UFT I couldnt identify the object of expand icon or the webelement. By creating object i can expand the tree but it takes more time to identify the Object.

I m using .Net, silverline, Activex and Web Addin.

Can anybody help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: What does the Object Spy show?

Comment: Its showing the object as webelement through Object spy. While recording is shows nothing.

Comment: "while recording"?  Do you mean while running?  Or that you are recording the actions and clicking the expand icon for the tree view is registering nothing in the recorded script?

Comment: Not while running. Yes it not registering any scripts while record and playback of the item.

Comment: Have you added the item to the object repository? You need to determine what the action is that achieves the goal you want and cause that to be fired.  You will almost definitely need to step beyond the absolute basics of record/playback to achieve this if the steps are not being recorded.